# How can i center a popup usercontrol in windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I want to center a popup usercontrol in the middle of the screen, how can I do this?

```
 Popup p = new Popup();
 p.Child = new loadingtest();

  p.isOpen = true;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var p = new Popup();
var content = new TextBox { Text = "hello world!" };
p.Child = content;
p.VerticalOffset = (this.ActualHeight - content.ActualHeight) / 2;
p.HorizontalOffset = (this.ActualWidth - content.ActualWidth) / 2;
p.IsOpen = true;
```

Where `this` is PhoneApplicationPage and popup is child of the `LayoutRoot` Grid.

Comment: Wooow! This platform is so amazing!!